# Yii searching duplicated results

Tags: yii, duplicates, yii1.x

**I'm new to Yii and this is not my code**

When i search something, the results are duplicated, Like
Results:
product1
product1
product2
product2

And I'm sure that the problem is coming from the Controller because i checked the view.
The Controller:

```
public function actionIndex($q){



  $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
      $criteria->with=array('cat','postDesc');
  $criteria->together=true;
 // $criteria->compare('post.pack_type',2);
 $criteria->compare('cat.zone','Group',true);
 $criteria->compare('postDesc.name',$q,true);

 // $criteria->compare('category_id',$id); 


     $this->pageTitle = "The search resluts for:".$q;
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerMetaTag(Helpers::config('meta_keyword'), 'keywords');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerMetaTag(Helpers::config('meta_description'), 'description');



$provider=new CActiveDataProvider('PostCategory', array(
         'pagination'=>array(
    'pageSize'=> Yii::app()->user->getState('pageSize',Yii::app()->params['defaultPageSize']),
),

        'criteria'=>$criteria,
         'sort' => array(
            'defaultOrder' => 't.post_id desc',
        ),

    ));




 $this->render('index',array(

        'dataProvider'=>$provider,
        'cat'=>$cat

    ));


}

public function actionItem($id){
    $model=Post::model()->findByPK((int)$id);

     $this->pageTitle = $model->desc->name;
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerMetaTag(Helpers::config('meta_keyword'), 'keywords');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerMetaTag(Helpers::config('meta_description'), 'description');

    $images=PostImage::model()->findAll(array('condition'=>'post_id='.$id));
    $attrs=PostAttr::model()->findAll(array('condition'=>'post_id='.$id,'order'=>'post_attr_id'));
    $media=PostMedia::model()->findAll(array('condition'=>'post_id='.$id));
     $this->render('item',array(

        //'dataProvider'=>$provider,
        'model'=>$model,
        'images'=>$images,
        'attrs'=>$attrs,
        'media'=>$media,

    ));

}
```

So I want it to send not two, but one result of every product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may happen if your model contains multiple `postDesc` or `cat`  related records. Solution may differ depending on what result you want to achieve in this situation, but the simplest one is probably group by `PostCategory` private key field:

```
$criteria->group = 't.id';
```